# opencv: C2668: 'cvRound': ambiguous call to overloaded function

Tags: opencv

I am using opencv3.2 in Qt5.7. Here below are part of my codes:

```
  for(int i=0;i<contour[0].size();i++)
  {
    if(contour[0][i].x>xmax) xmax = contour[0][i].x;
    if(contour[0][i].x<xmin) xmin = contour[0][i].x;
    if(contour[0][i].y>ymax) ymax = contour[0][i].y;
    if(contour[0][i].y<ymin) ymin = contour[0][i].y;
  }
  int step = cvRound(contour[0].size()/16); #this line causes the error
```

The building error is:

```
error C2668: 'cvRound': ambiguous call to overloaded function
C:\opencv-3.2.0\mybuild\include\opencv2/core/fast_math.hpp(232): note: could be 'int cvRound(int)'
C:\opencv-3.2.0\mybuild\include\opencv2/core/fast_math.hpp(201): note: or       'int cvRound(float)'
C:\opencv-3.2.0\mybuild\include\opencv2/core/fast_math.hpp(93): note: or       'int cvRound(double)'
```

Anybody can help with the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to cast the parameters of the Round. You can write (float) in front of them. This way you help the compiler to find the correct Round function (the one that takes a float argument, for example)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by changing:

```
int step = cvRound(contour[0].size()/16);
```

to:

```
int step = cvRound((double)contour[0].size()/16);
```